# hdf5 keras model - very large. Re-training gives OOM error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a network and saved the model as a hdf5 file. I am using the Keras library for training. But the file is very large ~ 3.6GB. I am unable to continue the training process, because the program throws an "Out of memory" error. I reduced the batch size from 128 to 8, and the same error is thrown. I would like to retrain the existing model when I encounter new data/Want to train for a few more epochs.

Using 12GB GPU RAM, 65GB CPU RAM.

2GB training images, 1GB training labels.

Any way to counter this?

Comment: Do you need to use the whole file for training? Seem like some people have advices on this problem [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1355)

Comment: What do you mean by the "whole file". The file stores the model and weights right? I am saving in this manner:
        model.save('model.hdf5')

Comment: Sorry, badly worded, when do you have the problem? When you train the model? Maybe lowering again the batch size or using less data to train would help?

Comment: The problem is when I load the trained model to continue training on a few more epochs on the same training data. When I had first trained the model, I used a batch size of 128. Reducing it down to even 8 didn't help. I could reduce it further, but I posted here looking for a different solution.

Comment: Then sorry I don't think i can help. Best idea I would have would be to either lower batch size, use less data to train (I don't know how big is the data you use as training but do you need as much?). Maybe though you should edit your question and add if you use GPU and maybe what ram/GPU you have. After [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1817) some people had fix for it. Also this module [may help](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_util) "This utility parses LOG_MEMORY messages out of TensorFlow vlog output and builds timeline of memory allocations".

Comment: After seeing you specs I feel strange that you get an OOM like that. Maybe someone more experienced would know better but I would look at some [memory visualisation](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_util) module. Some time ago tensorflow had memory management problem, maybe it's just something that you can easily debug (like tensorflow not deallocating something by itself). If you use GPU you can use [that](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_probe_ops) to query about memory. Found theses module [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/492)

Comment: I ran into same problem some time ago. Updating my keras and tensorflow to the latest version helped me out